# Find maximum value in dataframe with related column name and index

Tags: python, pandas, max

Let's take this small dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Name=['Jason_Fly','Alan_Smith','Steve_Rowland'], Col1=[1,2,3], Col2=[1,3,9],Col3=[5,6,8]))

            Name  Col1  Col2  Col3
0      Jason_Fly     1     1     5
1     Alan_Smith     2     3     6
2  Steve_Rowland     3     9     8
```

I would like to get the maximum value in the dataframe, with the name of the related column and the index (or ideally, the corresponding value in column Name).

**Expected output :**
Maximum : 9
Corresponding column : Col2
Corresponding index : 2 | Corresponding value in column Name : Steve_Rowland

How please could I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert `Name` column to `index`, so is possible get first maximum per columns and rows and use [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index('Name')

max1 = df1.to_numpy().max()
print (max1)
9

c = df1.max(axis=0).idxmax()
print (c)
Col2

n = df1.max(axis=1).idxmax()
print (n)
Steve_Rowland
```

Another solution is get position of maximum values and indexing first match values:

```
max1 = df1.to_numpy().max()
print (max1)
9

a,b  = np.where(df1 == max1)
print (a)
[2]

print (b)
[1]

c = df1.columns[b[0]]
print (c)
Col2

n = df1.index[a[0]]
print (n)
Steve_Rowland
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. Perfectly works except for df1.to_numpy().max(), I have this error : "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'"

Comment: @Ewdlam - It is because last version of pandas, for lower versions use `.values` instead `.numpy()`